# param reference to bean not being passed into composite component

Tags: jsf, components, composite

i'm having a bit of trouble with a composite component in JSF 2.1 vanilla (on glassfish 3.1).  the simplified version of my problem is here:

[composite component]

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <!-- INTERFACE -->
    <cc:interface>

            <cc:attribute name="value" required="true"/>
            <cc:attribute name="title" required="false" default=""/>

            <cc:editableValueHolder name="inputTarget" targets="labeledInputField"/>

    </cc:interface>

    <!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
    <cc:implementation>

            <p:inputText id="labeledInputField" 
                label="#{cc.attrs.title}"
                value="#{cc.attrs.value}" 
                title="#{cc.attrs.title}">

                <cc:insertChildren/>

            </p:inputText>

    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

[implemented in]

```
              <!-- thisPerson is passed in via ui:param to the facelet containing this code.  
                it works in other (non-composite) components on the page -->

              <comp:labeledInputText
                  id="baseUsername"
                  value="#{controller.username}"
                    title="#{bundle.Username}">

                  <f:validator for="inputTarget" binding="#{thisPerson.usernameValidator}"/>
                  <f:converter for="inputTarget" converterId="#{whiteSpaceTrimConverter}"/>

              </comp:labeledInputText>
```

the problem is, the "thisPerson.usernameValidator" is evaluating to NULL, which then causes the com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl to then skip to the code that attempts to load the validator by "validatorID" which is not set because we're trying to send in the validator by "binding".  is there a way to get the composite to evaluate the ui:param value, or a workaround that does not require reworking the validator (it's a huge anti-pattern and i don't have time to reverse the damage right now).  assume the validator HAS to come in via binding.

i know the composite works because in a different facelet, i have the validator binding against a concrete bean reference, rather than a "soft" reference, and it works like a champ.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing your exact JSF implementation, I am going to assume Mojarra, you may be running into the following known bug.

http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2040

Regardless if this is your exact problem or not, you can try to disable partial state saving and see if this resolves your issue.  If it does then that means that you are facing this issue, which apparently was (fixed?) in later versions of Mojarra.

Another possibility would be to simply use `renderFacet` instead of `insertChildren` and insert your validators in the form of a facet.

Comment: i will try the renderFacet approach and report back my results.  thanks for the idea.  /cross fingers

Comment: using facet did not help.  i'm guessing it's a phase timing issue (the CC is probably being constituted before the param is available).  unfortunate.  i'm going to leave this "unanswered" just in case someone knows of a functional workaround.

Comment: even though there is no "work around" this is a good commentary on the question